# Searching contents of a file using keywords inside array : PHP

Tags: php

I have 3 keywords inside array `$val[1]` :e.g `one, two, three`

and the following code:

```
foreach ($bus as $val){

$val = preg_split('/-./', $val, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // split by _ 
$val[1] = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\(.*/', '', $val[1])); // remove () if found
$val[1] = trim(preg_replace("/\s*\.\.\.*/", '', $val[1])); // remove ... if found
    $pattern = "/.*$val[1].*/i";
    $data3 = file_get_contents("foo.txt");
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data3, $matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $v){
        echo $pattern."<BR>".$v."<BR>";} }
```

However when I do the last `echo $pattern` in the loop, I found out that it only prints out `/.*two.*/i` (meaning it's using only the second keyword to search the file) as opposed to outside of it where it is able to print all keywords

```
/.*one.*/i
/.*two.*/i
/.*three.*/i
```

Where did I go wrong in the code? (I'll only be getting 3 lines of text as the result as each keyword will only return one result)

EDIT: Think i left out an important part of the code, I've edited it to show it more accurately - so I dont think I've been overwriting $val

Examples of what $bus will print

```
Ayer Rajah Avenue-.Opp JVC Electron... 
Ayer Rajah Avenue-.JVC Electronics ... 
Portsdown Road-.Opp Portsdown Camp ...
```

Comment: You are overwriting your $val array in the foreach .. check my answer below. Also you might want to accept answers to some of your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are over writing your $val array!

```
foreach($val[1] as $keyword)    //when you do "as $val" that means for the 2nd time.. $val[1] does not exist!
{
     $pattern = "/.*$keyword.*/i"; ...
```

Comment: Think i left out an important part of the code, I've edited it to show it more accurately - so I dont think I've been overwriting $val

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like:

```
foreach ($val as $keyword) {
    // replace usage of $val with $keyword
```

You are taking the second element of the array, `$val[1]`, which is `two`, and then applying a `foreach` against `two`.  Then you are storing it right back on top of your original variable, `$val`.

**Edit**

You are only working with `$val[1]`.  Don't you need to apply all of your logic to all of the entries in `$val`?

```
$val = preg_split('/-./', $val, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // split by _ 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
    $val[$i] = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\(.*/', '', $val[$i])); // remove () if found
    $val[$i] = trim(preg_replace("/\s*\.\.\.*/", '', $val[$i])); // remove ... if found
    $pattern = "/.*$val[$i].*/i";

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Think i left out an important part of the code, I've edited it to show it more accurately - so I dont think I've been overwriting $val

Answer (score 0):

use

> PREG_SET_ORDER

as 4th argument in `preg_match_all`

[reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using different names for your array and the element in your foreach statement.

Also I'd recommend you put file_get_contents outside your loop for efficiency reasons.

Finally, your last foreach loop should uses $matches, not $matches[0] (which just calls the first match.